# Unable to send email using nodemailer in production server

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, smtp, nodemailer

I have some issue with sending email using nodemailer in nodejs.
Like it is sending mail from local server but when it is in production server it giving response that suceessful but not reciving any email.
It only happening in server not in local.
I have checked with firewall and SMTP port all are correct. I have tested it by diabling the firewall. Please help me with this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fa9IO.png)

I am expecting anyone just help me to understand this issue that what i am missing.

This is my code

```js
export const securityEmailSender = async (
  senderEmail: string,
  subject: string,
  body: string
): Promise<void> => {
  const transporter: Transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: appConfig.host,
    port: appConfig.port,
    // secure: true,
    auth: {
      user: "***",
      pass: "***",
    },
  });

  // setup email data with unicode symbols
  const mailOptions = {
    from: `${appConfig.brandName} <***`,
    to: senderEmail,
    subject: subject,
    html: body,
  };

  // send mail with defined transport object
  try {
    const info = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
    console.log("Message sent: " + info.response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your image shows that 5 messages were sent ... how do you propose we debug this?

Comment: Sorry for that. I have add the code, now you can check. It is working fine in my local server but if i deploy the code to VM it is not working